# Tomcat service can't start: access denied

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, tomcat, windows-services

I am using Tomcat on a Windows server and faced a problem while updating the Tomcat version. The problem is that the assigned user doesn't have the rights to start Tomcat.

Here are my attempts with Tomcat versions:

- v8.5.43/ -> Tomcat started successfully
- v8.5.45/ -> access denied
- v8.5.46/ -> access denied
- v8.5.47/ -> access denied
- v8.5.49/ -> access denied
- v8.5.50/ -> access denied
- v9.0.30/ -> access denied

The user already has the LogonAsService privilege. Do you know which rights the user who starts Tomcat should have?

Comment: Can you start Tomcat manually?

Comment: No, unfortunately not with this user. but only with the local system user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution:

from Tomcat 8.5.44 the user must have read and exeute permissions on the Tomcat-Install-Directory.

```
ICACLS "Tomcat-Install-Directory" /grant %UserName%:(OI)(CI)(RX) /T
```

[Source](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55969)